# Azure - Authenticating Service Management Requests

Tags: c#, sql, .net, azure, azure-sql-database

I need to perform few Azure SQL operations. I have an Azure AD native application. I'm using first approach from following article to aquire the token.

https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/azure/ee460782.aspx

Now following [this](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/azure/dn509571.aspx) article, I'm using the above token to perform the db operation.

```
static void HttpPost(string sourceDb, string targetDb, string pointInTime)
        {
            var client = new HttpClient();
            string uri = "https://management.core.windows.net:8443/" + AzureSubscriptionId + "/services/sqlservers/servers/" + AzureSqlServerName + "/restoredatabaseoperations";
            HttpRequestMessage request = new HttpRequestMessage(HttpMethod.Post, uri);
            request.Headers.Add("Authorization", "Bearer " + accessToken);
            request.Headers.Add("x-ms-version", "2012-03-01");

            string payload = File.ReadAllText("Resources\\Backup.xml");
            payload = payload.Replace("$SourceDb", sourceDb);
            payload = payload.Replace("$TargetDb", targetDb);
            payload = payload.Replace("$PointInTime", pointInTime);
            request.Content = new StringContent(payload, Encoding.UTF8, "application/xml");

            HttpResponseMessage response = client.SendAsync(request).GetAwaiter().GetResult();
            if (response.Content != null)
            {
                string ss = response.Content.ReadAsStringAsync().Result;
            }
        }
```

But the error I receive is:

`"<Error xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/windowsazure" xmlns:i="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"><Code>AuthenticationFailed</Code><Message>A security token exception occured for the received JWT token.</Message></Error>"`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

According to you mentioned [Create Database Restore Request (Classic) REST API](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42110286/azure-authenticating-service-management-requests), this command is used for classic deployment model. We should use the new REST API, and it is also mentioned in your mentioned document.

> You should use the newer [Resource Manager based REST API](https://msdn.microsoft.com/library/azure/mt163571.aspx) commands located here.

We could use the ARM REST  [Create or Update DataBase](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/azure/mt163685.aspx) API. About how to get the token, we need to to registry AD App and assign role to application, more info please refer to [official document](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-resource-manager/resource-group-create-service-principal-portal#create-an-active-directory-application). I send the http request from fiddler and it works correctly for me. Header and body info please refer to the screenshot.

[image]

[image]

Body info:

```
{
  "properties": {
    "edition": "Standard",
    "requestedServiceObjectiveName": "S1",
    "sourceDatabaseId": "/subscriptions/{your subscriptionId}/resourceGroups/{ResourceGroup}/providers/Microsoft.Sql/servers/{servername}/databases/sourcedatabasename",
    "createMode": "PointInTimeRestore",
    "restorePointInTime": "2017-02-09T10:28:20.21+08:00" //source database restorePointTime
  },
  "location": "East Asia",
  "tags": {}
}
```

We also can use Microsoft Azure SQL Management Library for .NET to that. 
   `SqlMgmtClient.Databases.CreateOrUpdate(resourceGroupName, serverName, databaseName, DatabaseCreateOrUpdateParameters)`;

We could refer to the [tutorial](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/azure/mt163685.aspx) to get started.  I do a demo for it. More details please refer to the following steps

1.Create a console app and install the required libraries (detail refer to  [tutorial](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/azure/mt163685.aspx))

2.After registry an application, we could get tenantId, applicationId, 
SecretKey, then with subscriptionId to  get the authentication token.

3.Create SqlManagementClient object with token

```
var _sqlMgmtClient = new SqlManagementClient(new TokenCloudCredentials(_subscriptionId, _token.AccessToken));
```

4.Create DatabaseCreateOrUpdateParameters  according to our requirement.
Take restore database from a source database for example:

```
 CreateMode = DatabaseCreateMode.PointInTimeRestore, //craete mode from pointtimerestore
 Edition = databaseEdition,
 SourceDatabaseId = "/subscriptions/subscriptionId/resourceGroups/groupname/providers/Microsoft.Sql/servers/AzureSQlname/databases/databaseName", //source database Id
 RestorePointInTime  = DateTime.Parse("2017-02-09T02:28:20.21Z"), //resore point Time
 RequestedServiceObjectiveName = "S1"
```

5. run the demo and check from the portal.

   [image]

   [image]

democode:

```
       static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            _token = GetToken(_tenantId, _applicationId, _applicationSecret);
            Console.WriteLine("Token acquired. Expires on:" + _token.ExpiresOn);
            // Instantiate management clients:
            _resourceMgmtClient = new ResourceManagementClient(new Microsoft.Rest.TokenCredentials(_token.AccessToken));
            _sqlMgmtClient = new SqlManagementClient(new TokenCloudCredentials(_subscriptionId, _token.AccessToken));
            DatabaseCreateOrUpdateResponse dbr = CreateOrUpdateDatabase(_sqlMgmtClient, _resourceGroupName, _serverName, _databaseName, _databaseEdition, _databasePerfLevel);
            Console.WriteLine("Database: " + dbr.Database.Id);
        }
        private static AuthenticationResult GetToken(string tenantId, string applicationId, string applicationSecret)
        {
            AuthenticationContext authContext = new AuthenticationContext("https://login.windows.net/" + tenantId);
            _token = authContext.AcquireToken("https://management.core.windows.net/", new ClientCredential(applicationId, applicationSecret));
            return _token;
        }
        static DatabaseCreateOrUpdateResponse CreateOrUpdateDatabase(SqlManagementClient sqlMgmtClient, string resourceGroupName, string serverName, string databaseName, string databaseEdition, string databasePerfLevel)
        {
            // Retrieve the server that will host this database
            Server currentServer = sqlMgmtClient.Servers.Get(resourceGroupName, serverName).Server;

            // Create a database: configure create or update parameters and properties explicitly
            DatabaseCreateOrUpdateParameters newDatabaseParameters = new DatabaseCreateOrUpdateParameters()
            {
                Location = currentServer.Location,
                Properties = new DatabaseCreateOrUpdateProperties
                {
                    CreateMode = DatabaseCreateMode.PointInTimeRestore,
                    Edition = databaseEdition,
                    SourceDatabaseId = "/subscriptions/subscriptionId/resourceGroups/tomnewgroup/providers/Microsoft.Sql/servers/tomsunsqltest/databases/sourceDatabaseName",
                    RestorePointInTime  = DateTime.Parse("2017-02-09T02:28:20.21Z"),//Restore Point time
                    RequestedServiceObjectiveName = databasePerfLevel
                }
            };

            DatabaseCreateOrUpdateResponse dbResponse = sqlMgmtClient.Databases.CreateOrUpdate(resourceGroupName, serverName, databaseName, newDatabaseParameters);
            return dbResponse;
        }
```

packages.config file:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<packages>
  <package id="Hyak.Common" version="1.0.2" targetFramework="net462" />
  <package id="Microsoft.Azure.Common" version="2.1.0" targetFramework="net462" />
  <package id="Microsoft.Azure.Common.Authentication" version="1.7.0-preview" targetFramework="net462" />
  <package id="Microsoft.Azure.Common.Dependencies" version="1.0.0" targetFramework="net462" />
  <package id="Microsoft.Azure.Management.ResourceManager" version="1.4.0-preview" targetFramework="net462" />
  <package id="Microsoft.Azure.Management.Sql" version="0.51.0-prerelease" targetFramework="net462" />
  <package id="Microsoft.Bcl" version="1.1.9" targetFramework="net462" />
  <package id="Microsoft.Bcl.Async" version="1.0.168" targetFramework="net462" />
  <package id="Microsoft.Bcl.Build" version="1.0.14" targetFramework="net462" />
  <package id="Microsoft.IdentityModel.Clients.ActiveDirectory" version="2.18.206251556" targetFramework="net462" />
  <package id="Microsoft.Net.Http" version="2.2.22" targetFramework="net462" />
  <package id="Microsoft.Rest.ClientRuntime" version="2.1.0" targetFramework="net462" />
  <package id="Microsoft.Rest.ClientRuntime.Azure" version="3.1.0" targetFramework="net462" />
  <package id="Microsoft.Rest.ClientRuntime.Azure.Authentication" version="2.0.1-preview" targetFramework="net462" />
  <package id="Newtonsoft.Json" version="6.0.8" targetFramework="net462" />
</packages>
```

Answer (score -1):

Please open a support case allowing us to better understand the issue